# How do I set initial value for ngx-intl-tel-input

Tags: angular, intl-tel-input

I am using ngx-intl-tel-input for phone number validation in my Angular project.

```
<form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="phoneForm">
<ngx-intl-tel-input 
[cssClass]="'custom'" 
[preferredCountries]="['us', 'gb']" 
[enablePlaceholder]="true"
[enableAutoCountrySelect]="true"
[value]="'+91 8888888888'"
name="phone" 
formControlName="phone"></ngx-intl-tel-input>
```

I need to set value for the field which is coming from server.

I have used `[value]` attribute, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 6):

In ngAfterViewInit, patch the value of phone with country code to the form control and detect changes.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.phoneForm.controls.phone.setValue('+919898989898');
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: what is cd?  what kind of variable is ?

Comment: `cd.detectChanges()` really did job for me! Thanks!

Comment: @qleoz12 you inject `ChangeDetectorRef` in your class, like this: `constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}`

Answer (score 1):

When you are using form control the easiest way is to set the initial value of the control.

For ngx-intl-tel-input is important your phone number to contains country code.

```
 this.yourFormGroup= this.formBuilder.group({
          phone: ['+918888888888', [Validators.required]],
        });
```